# How to solve the limit below?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

$lim_{z\to 0} e^{\frac{1}{z^4}} $. 
So I let $z=x+iy$ which gives $e^{\frac{1}{(x+iy)^4}}$ . This takes way to long to simplify. I'm not too sure which rays to use in order to find the limit.

Comment: Better use polar coordinates ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try it alongside $2$ different sequences? For example:
$$z_n:=\frac{1}{n}$$
And
$$z_n:=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}n}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{z\to 0} e^{\frac{1}{z^4}}$ does not exist, since the function $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z^4}}$  has an essential singularity at $z=0.$